# Android RxJava: как правильно подписать PublishSubject на множество Observable?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки и варианты как это поправить.

Задача: выдавать результаты вычислений асинхронно, по готовности.
Пример составлен для теста из рабочего кода, его можно использовать в IDE.

И как приведено в примере - работает и в рабочем примере заполняет ячейки лэйаута рандомно, но иногда один или два результата выпадают и иногда выполнение заканчивается ошибкой.

Думаю, что использовать `subject.onNext()` напрямую некорректно, т.к. нельзя потом проверить `subject.hasComplete()`, который не возвращает в таком случае `true`.
Проблема правильно подписать "subject" на все "observable", чтобы код работал асинхронно без ошибок.

Используется RxJava3. Gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.4'
}
```

Комментарии "TODO" в коде.

```
 private void run() {
    
    Log.d("APP", "INIT");

    PublishSubject<String> subject = exec(1000000);
    subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(unit -> {
            Log.d("STRING RESULT = ", unit);
            if (subject.hasComplete()) {
                //TODO: this condition should work if we use observable.subscribe(subject), not subject.onNext
                Log.d("SUBJECT", "COMPLETED");
            }
        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
}

private int insertValue = 1000000;

public PublishSubject<String> exec(int inputNumber) {
    PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    getListObservable(inputNumber)
        .flatMap(resultList -> getOperationsObservable()
        .flatMap(operationElem -> getResultListObservable(resultList)
            .map(listElem ->
                                    calculate(operationElem, listElem)
//TODO: should be smth like this, i.e. calculate.subscribe(subject)
//                        .subscribe(subject)
                                        .subscribe(subject::onNext)

                        )
                )
        ).subscribe();

    return subject;
}


private Observable<ArrayList<List<Integer>>> getListObservable(int inputNumber) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {

        ArrayList<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer[] populatedArray = new Integer[inputNumber];
        Arrays.fill(populatedArray, insertValue);

        list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(populatedArray)));
        list.add(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(populatedArray)));
        list.add(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(populatedArray)));

        return list;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
}


private Observable<String> calculate(ListOperationName operationName, List<Integer> list) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double start = getTime();

        synchronized (list) {

            switch (operationName) {
                case ADD_FIRST:
                    list.add(0, insertValue);
                    break;
                case ADD_MID:
                    list.add(list.size() / 2, insertValue);
                    break;
                case ADD_LAST:
                    list.add(insertValue);
                    break;
                case SEARCH:
                    //noinspection unused
                    boolean contains = list.contains(insertValue);
                    break;
                case RM_FIRST:
                    list.remove(0);
                    break;
                case RM_MID:
                    list.remove(list.size() / 2);
                    break;
                case RM_LAST:
                    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Double.toString(getTime() - start);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
}

private Observable<ListOperationName> getOperationsObservable() {
    return Observable.fromArray(ListOperationName.values());
}

private Observable<List<Integer>> getResultListObservable(ArrayList<List<Integer>> list) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list);
}

private double getTime() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}

public enum ListOperationName {
    ADD_FIRST,
    ADD_MID,
    ADD_LAST,
    SEARCH,
    RM_FIRST,
    RM_MID,
    RM_LAST;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем вообще этот `subject`?  Попробуй:

```
public Observable<String> exec(int inputNumber) {
return getListObservable(inputNumber)
    .flatMap(resultList -> getOperationsObservable()
        .flatMap(operationElem -> getResultListObservable(resultList)
            .map(listElem -> calculate(operationElem, listElem))
        )
    );
}
```

и затем:

```
private void run() {

Log.d("APP", "INIT");

exec(1000000)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(unit -> {
        Log.d("STRING RESULT = ", unit);
        if (subject.hasComplete()) {
            //TODO: this condition should work if we use observable.subscribe(subject), not subject.onNext
            Log.d("SUBJECT", "COMPLETED");
        }
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
}
```